# Google places API does this violate the TOC?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to have a little search box, where the user can search for a place (using API), then when they select a place e.g "statue of liberty, new york", I want to take them to a detail
page I.E mysite/ID/statue-of-liberty-new-york

and then let them do some things on that page,

The only data I want from google on the detail page, is the places ID and of course the name and address of the place, that's it then I want to do my own stuff and attach my own data to the places.

I'm a bit annoyed it's hard to understand what is acceptable, they should have expressed this TOC in laymans terms.

Here's some relveant info from their [TOC](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms):

a) No Unauthorized Copying, Modification, Creation of Derivative Works, or Display of the Content. You must not copy, translate, modify, or create a derivative work (including creating or contributing to a database) of, or publicly display any Content or any part thereof except as explicitly permitted under these Terms. For example, the following are prohibited: (i) creating server-side modification of map tiles; (ii) stitching multiple static map images together to display a map that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation; (iii) creating mailing lists or telemarketing lists based on the Content; or (iv) exporting, writing, or saving the Content to a third party's location-based platform or service.

(b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or other local listings information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relevant policies for your question you'll find here: https://developers.google.com/places/policies

1. you **may** use the searchbox and you **also may** use the results to show them on a page without showing a google-map
2. it's still not clear if you use any type of map inside your application, but when you do so, you **may not** use any data delivered by the places-service to use them on this map(e.g. you may not use the latLng of the place-result to create a marker on this map)
3. you **must** show the google-logo (because you show data -name and address- received from the service)
4. when the response contains `html_attributions` for the place  you also **must** show these `html_attributions`

Comment: Thanks, that's a big help!

Comment: Is that still correct in 2016? I'm asking about 2nd point. I can't see in privacy policy if there are any prohibited activities about Maps API and Places API

Comment: *If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a map, **that map must be provided by Google.***

Comment: Oh that means the data retrieved from Places API can be used only on Google map. I misunderstood that I can't use this data at all. Thanks.