# google places library without map

Tags: google-maps, google-places

I am trying to use the google places library for a nearby search request:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

i just want to pull the json response and put it in a html list, i do now want to show results on a map or something else. I do not want to use map at all. But in documentation it states that there has to be a map

```js
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(**map**);
```

in order to pass it as an argument in the PlacesService function. What i do now is adding a map with height:0 but it still consumes much amount of memory (i develop a sencha touch 2 app and memory is important). Is there any workaround of using nearby search requests without a map? I do not want to use the Google Places API as it does not support JSONP requests.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

As documented the PlacesService accepts as argument either a map or an **node where to render the attributions for the results**.

So you only have to use the node (a node being an html element) instead of the map.

Please note: hiding the attributions violates the places-policies(also hiding the map when used as argument, because the map will show the attributions)

This also may be interesting to you: [Google places API does this violate the TOC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313215/google-places-api-does-this-violate-the-toc/14322983#14322983)

---

#### Example: in a nutshell

If you're using jQuery:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($('#tag-id').get(0));
```

If plain Javascript:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
```

Then carry on as usual [with the rest of the example code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests):

```
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

---

#### Example: using details returned

[Live demo of this example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AdrienBe/Lz6sspzd/).

Note: This example uses `jQuery`.

```
<ul class="reviews__content" id="reviews__content">
</ul>
<div id="service-helper"></div>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY_HERE&libraries=places&callback=getRelevantGoogleReviews">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.getRelevantGoogleReviews = function(){
     var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($('#service-helper').get(0)); // note that it removes the content inside div with tag '#service-helper'

     service.getDetails({
         placeId: 'ChIJAwEf5VFQqEcRollj8j_kqnE'  // get a placeId using https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-id
        }, function(place, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              var resultcontent = '';
              for (i=0; i<place.reviews.length; ++i) {
                //window.alert('Name:' + place.name + '. ID: ' + place.place_id + '. address: ' + place.formatted_address);
                resultcontent += '<li class="reviews__item">'
                resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-er">' + place.reviews[i].author_name + '</div>';
                var reviewDate = new Date(place.reviews[i].time * 1000);
                var reviewDateMM = reviewDate.getMonth() + 1;
                var reviewDateFormatted = reviewDate.getDate() + '/' + reviewDateMM + '/' + reviewDate.getFullYear(); 
                resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-date">' + reviewDateFormatted + '</div>';
                resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-rating reviews__review-rating--' + place.reviews[i].rating +'"></div>';
                if (!!place.reviews[i].text){
                  resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-comment">' + place.reviews[i].text + '</div>';
                }
                resultcontent += '</li>'
              }
              $('#reviews__content').append(resultcontent);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does a node mean here, does it mean an html element?

Comment: Should the node be a div? Does the div need any special properties? How do you actually render the attributions for the results? Is rendering the attributions the same as putting them the places in an HTML list?

Comment: Hey, Dr.Molle would you be able to expand your answer? (I know it was almost two years ago, but putting a node as argument fails for me despite docs)

Comment: please define "fails"!

Comment: Here is exactly what you need to do if you're using jquery: places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($('#myDiv').get(0));

Comment: aka `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'))`

Comment: @supersaiyan the code mentioned does NOT show a map (as required).

Comment: As of 1/12/2017 according to the  [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies)  

**"If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a page or view that does not also display a Google Map, you must show a "Powered by Google" logo with that data"**

. However I cannot find anywhere in the documentaion how to initialize the places service without specifying a map??

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just did a solid 2 hours of googling before running into this -- var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get location data from a place_id you can do it using the Geocoder class:[Here the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-place-id). With this class you can pass a place_id to the method geocode() and get coordinates and other location data.

Comment: thank you very much. just quick fix: it's the "Geocoder" class

Comment: and it is under [Geolocation API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/geolocation.googleapis.com)

Answer (score 2):

Was making a custom address autocomplete for a sign up form.

```
import {useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'React'

function AutoCompleteInput(){

const [predictions, setPredictions] = useState([]);
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const [selectedPlaceDetail, addSelectedPlaceDetail] = useState({})
const predictionsRef = useRef();


useEffect(
()=>{
      try {
        autocompleteService.current.getPlacePredictions({ input }, predictions => {
          setPredictions(predictions);
        });
      } catch (err) {
       // do something
      }
    }
}, [input])

const handleAutoCompletePlaceSelected = placeId=>{
 if (window.google) {
      const PlacesService = new window.google.maps.places.PlacesService(predictionsRef.current);
      try {
        PlacesService.getDetails(
          {
            placeId,
            fields: ['address_components'],
          },
         place => addSelectedPlaceDetail(place)
        );
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
}

return (
  <>
   <input onChange={(e)=>setInput(e.currentTarget.value)}
    <div ref={predictionsRef}
     { predictions.map(prediction => <div onClick={ ()=>handleAutoCompletePlaceSelected(suggestion.place_id)}> prediction.description </div> )
   }
   </div>
  <>
 )
}
```

So basically, you setup the autocomplete call, and get back the predictions results in your local state.

from there, map and show the results with a click handler that will do the follow up request to the places services with access to the getDetails method for the full address object or whatever fields you want.

you then save that response to your local state and off you go.

Comment: what is `autocompleteService` ?

Comment: @asus it is a reference to `new window.google.maps.places.AutocompleteService()`

Comment: So instead of a `google.maps.Map` you just need to pass any old DOM element to the `google.maps.places.PlacesService` constructor...seems a bit strange?

Answer (score 1):

Just seen Man asking in a comment above **How to initialise the places service without initialising a map?** so I thought I would add it here.

```
placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($('#predicted-places').get(0));
```

You will need to create an html element with that id first though.

Answer (score -1):

I have come across the same problem.

> Why use Maps javascript Api when Places Api is already enabled.Is it an additional price to pay for this simple task?

Maps Javascript API is not used in this code.All the google.maps.Map API methods are taken out. It works fine on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).

Just checkout whether it works on local PC.Most of the time it gives the 403 error when i tried running it on local PC storage and using limited requests provided by google API console.

*acquire an API key from the google developer console and insert it in the YOUR_API_KEY slot at the script tag of the code*
*Don't try to run the code here.obviously.The API key needs to be replaced.*

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

  var options = {
    types: ['establishment']
  };

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

  autocomplete.setFields(['place_id', 'geometry', 'name', 'formatted_address', 'formatted_phone_number', 'opening_hours', 'website', 'photos']);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', placechange);

  function placechange() {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var photos = place.photos;

    document.getElementById('place_name').textContent = place.name;
    document.getElementById('place_id').textContent = place.place_id;
    document.getElementById('place_address').textContent = place.formatted_address;
    document.getElementById('phone_no').textContent = place.formatted_phone_number;
    document.getElementById('open_time').textContent = place.opening_hours.weekday_text[0];
    document.getElementById('open_now').textContent = place.opening_hours.open_now;
    document.getElementById('photo').src = photos[0].getUrl();
    document.getElementById('photo').style = "width:50%;";
    document.getElementById('website').textContent = place.website;


  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.controls {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 29px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

.controls:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a business">
</div>

<div id="info-table">
  Name: <span id="place_name"></span><br> Place id: <span id="place_id"></span><br> Address :<span id="place_address"></span><br> Phone : <span id="phone_no"></span><br> Openhours: <span id="open_time"></span><br> Open Now : <span id="open_now"></span><br>  website : <span id="website"></span><br> photo :<br> <img id="photo" src="" style="display:none;" />
</div>

<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
  <strong>Place ID:</strong> <span id="place-id"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: The OP specifically wants to use the PlacesService, which you are not doing in your example. So this answer does not relate to the question!