# Initialize GMaps Places API without Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When using Google Places API, what is the best way of hiding the map itself ?

We only need the search auto-complete, and our users don't need to see the map itself.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?authuser=2#place_search_requests

Comment: duplicate of [Can't remove map part of function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696124/cant-remove-map-part-of-function)

Comment: duplicate of [google places library without map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343965/google-places-library-without-map)

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete?authuser=2#video

Basically the Autocomplete constructor has a constructor overload

= new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( htmlInput, autoCompleteOptions )

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, { bounds: defaultBounds });

And this is not violating the TOS at all, reading the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete?authuser=2#video above.